# Pandoc LaTeX Error with .sty

Tags: pdftex, packages, pandoc

I started to use Fedora 38 yesterday and I would like to use it for a professional usage.
I installed *MiKTeX*, *pandoc* and removed *texlive-scheme-full*.
I also did the *dnf's update* and so on.

I tried to convert my *.md* file with a *fontfamily* specification in the YAML header.
Everytime I specify a *fontfamily*, I have this following error in my console when I enter the following line command : `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `EBGaramond.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.10 \usepackage
```

My console says that the *fontfamily* that I specified in the YAML is on my computer. I tested many fonts (*EB Garamond*, *Times*, etc.), the results are similar. I precise that every other packages that are necessary in the conversion work fine. When some are missing, it's automatically installed. Therefore, why .sty fonts don't do the same ?

This works perfectly on my Windows terminal. But you know.. I would like to avoid this option.

I have been searching on the Internet since midday but I can't find a solution.
Could you help me? Consider that I am a newbie in Linux distribution. Although I'll do my best to do my part in this.

Here is my *.md* file :

```
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[french]{babel} 
    - \usepackage{path,wallpaper}
    - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    - \usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
fontsize: 12pt
fontfamily: EB Garamond
---

# testing the fontfamily bug

p1x3n
```

Comment: First: things will be easier to debug if you only have one tex distribution. Choose either texlive or miktex, but not both (for linux I would suggest texlive). Second: add a small text file to your question so we can reproduce the problem. Third: add the full .log file to your question so we can see which engine you use and which package exactly isn't found.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Done. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: There is no latex package named `EBGaramond` Try with `fontfamily: ebgaramond` instead  (capitalisation does matter) This package should be included in both texlive and miktex: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` is no longer necessary, that's the default since a couple of years

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It works. It works for *Times* too. So the problem was only the capitalisation? Therefore, why capitalisation works when I do the same convertion from the Windows Terminal?

Comment: You should NOT use the `times` package. Have a look at the `mathptmx`, `helvet` (option scaled=.9) or `courier` packages instead

Comment: (or switch to an unicode aware engine like lualatex, then you can directly use the fonts installed on your computer)

Comment: why miktex on linux? it has been ported to linux but it leaves you very much on your own with no community experience, I would expect well in excess of 99% of linux tex users use texlive.

Comment: "Therefore, why capitalisation works when I do the same convertion from the Windows Terminal? " the windows file system is not case sensitive so `TiMeS.sTY` is the same file as `times.sty` but on linux they would be different files (and `TiMeS.sTY` does not exist)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Why? After the OP added a MWE and their error message, the problem seems quite clear. What else would you need?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Simply because it worked on Windows, therefore I supposed that it was okay on Linux as well. Wrong guess. It seems that if we want to learn to use Linux we suppose to know the differencies between others system's logics and Linux's logic.

Thank you so much for your answers !

Comment: the mixed case name was always wrong even on windows (and latex will warn about it) but because on windows it is in fact the same file the error recovery is slightly different.